# My didSelectRowAtIndexPath not called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

didSelectRowAtIndexPath not called. I tried all the solutions posted over stack overflow.

```
func tableView(_tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
```

Comment: How would anyone be able to help with this little information? Please edit your post to include more context and what you have tried so far.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth only this single method have problem. numberOfRowsInSection,cellForRowAt working properly

Comment: are you connected the delegate to your current class

Comment: class LocationViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource,IndicatorInfoProvider,UITabBarControllerDelegate{
        
        self.tableMain.delegate = self
        self.tableMain.dataSource = self

Comment: if you don't have proper answer Please stop down voting.

Comment: There should be a *space* between `_` and `tableView` in your function signature: `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) {`

Comment: @vacawama Thanks for your reply. I tried but problem still exist.

Comment: Is your `func` at the top level of the UIViewController (not inside another func)? Please edit the question and add your `UIViewController` code and it will be easier for us to spot the problem.

Comment: Please give more information of your view controller class.

Comment: @Rumy Problem solved. thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross verify the following things at it prevents the **didSelectMethod** to work:

1. Is the `userInteraction` not disabled for `tableView`
2. Have not given any tap gesture to the main `UIView` i.e like for example

   ```
       // Tap Gesture
       let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(HomeVC.tapBlurButton(_:)))
       self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
   ```

**and use it like**

```
 @objc func tapBlurButton(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        tblZoneType.reloadData()
    }
```

This will prevent the interaction with the `tableView` **(Personally experienced the problem, and my didSelect was not called)** and i removed the code of tap gesture and it worked back

3. Have given the `dataSource` and `delegates` correctly.
4. Does not have any View covering the `tableView`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks bro.. self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture) this is the problem.

Comment: Some people have need to learn to you. without having knowledge down vote the question.

Comment: @RajkumarKumawat If it worked for you. Keep habit of approving it by green tick.

Answer (score 0):

Check your delegate methods are actually being called, you may not have hooked up the VC as the delegate/datasource

Comment: Sam I don't understand what are you trying to say. in another controller its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You might have **button** in that cell, and you might be trying to tap on that button (or) 
check in storyboard, for that tableView user interaction is enabled or not

Comment: Yes , user interaction is enabled and the cell contains only label.

Comment: what is the height of that tableview cell & tableview ?